# Problem with displaying the Field level error message on VF page

Tags: validation-rule

I have a validation rule which is display on Vf page with encoding form.

how can i solve below problem

Error Message : " Start date & time must be before the end date & time "

but it is displaying on VF page as

Error: Start date & time must be before the end date & time
[image]

Comment: Perhaps there is a way to avoid this encoding, but If I was you, I would just use the word "and" instead of "&" to sidestep the problem.

Comment: You can use &amp; instead of just & like "Start date &amp; time must be before the end date &amp; time"

Answer (score 1):

Everything what couldn't be done within visualforce could be done within javascript.

You could create script:

```
<script>
function replaceAmp() {
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName("errorMsg");
    if (x.length>0) {
        x[0].innerHTML = x[0].innerHTML.replace(/amp;/g, '');
    }
}
</script>
```

Wrap it with your field:

```
<apex:inputField value="{!opportunity.start_date__c}"> 
    <script type="text/javascript">
    (function(){
        replaceAmp();
    })();
    </script>
</apex:inputField>
```

It will be executed every time, when field finishes it's rendering